# Display XY using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

My final results from a model builder is a .dbf file with X and Y coordinates as shown in the image.

Is there any way to plot these coordinates on ArcMap using ModelBuilder?

[image]

Comment: Try the [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) tool after you create the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool you want for this is the Make XY Event Layer tool.

[image: model view]

If you set your x and y names as "x" and "y", ArcGIS will figure out which one to use for lat and long. Otherwise, you can easily set it by double-clicking on the tool in the model.

[image: tool properties]

As far as I can tell, the tool retains the information from the table.

Note that if you need a shapefile out of this, you will have to export the resulting layer, as it is just an event layer in memory.